# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe' when trying audio = AudioSegment.from_file()

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg, ffprobe, audiosegment

Trying to convert an audio file to wav format file using:

AudioSegment.from_file(input_audio_file).

Functionality works fine on local machine, however when deployed on Heroku seeing a following error logs:

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe'**

Comment: "ffmpeg is installed and ffprobe --version gives following output"—installed _where?_ How did you install it? Based on the "Apple clang" part, I'm guessing that's your development machine. You need to install it on Heroku, too.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, the issue you're facing is that Heroku is a cloud application platform and it can only access files which are in cloud storage.

The reason you're not facing the error in your local environment because the uploaded file is saved in your machine locally and it can be accessed easily but in case of deployed application, it cannot access that file.

What you have to do is configure a cloud storage like S3, Azure Blob Storage, etc. with your project, then your problem will be solved.